# OpenCV Masking error result tearing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javacv

I am trying to mask a binary image onto an original, most of the time it works however I am occasionally getting this:

[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?  Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Ok, So I have 2 images that I'm finding the difference between, which ends up being the hand.

[image] [image]

EXAMPLE OF A GOOD RESULT

[image]

I then convert the difference image to grey scale, binerize the image (using cvThreshold), and finally use the result as a mask on input2 (the original image w/ the hand). The final operation cvCopy is the one that seems to be causing this tearing, mind you it only happens sometimes (1/5 times roughly).

Here is what my Main.java looks like:

```
    import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
    import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
    import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CvHistogram;

    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;

    public class Main {

private static CanvasFrame AbsDiffFrame = new CanvasFrame("cvAbsDiff");
private static CanvasFrame SubDiffFrame = new CanvasFrame("cvSub");
private static CanvasFrame grayscale = new CanvasFrame("cvCvtColor CV_RGB2GRAY");
private static CanvasFrame binary = new CanvasFrame("cvThreshold CV_THRESH_BINARY");
private static CanvasFrame hsv = new CanvasFrame("cvCvtColor CV_RGB2HSV");
private static CanvasFrame cvMultiplyAcc = new CanvasFrame("cvMultiplyAcc");
private static CanvasFrame hsv2 = new CanvasFrame("cvCvtColor CV_RGB2HSV");
private static IplImage input1;
private static IplImage input2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AbsDiffFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    SubDiffFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    grayscale.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    binary.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    hsv.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    hsv2.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    cvMultiplyAcc.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    input1 = cvLoadImage("input1.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    input2 = cvLoadImage("input2.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    ImageProcessor imgProc = new ImageProcessor();

    AbsDiffFrame.showImage(imgProc.getAbsDifference(input1, input2));

    IplImage img = imgProc.getSubDifference(input2,input1);

    SubDiffFrame.showImage(img);

    IplImage hsvImg = imgProc.rgbToHSV(input2);

    hsv.showImage(hsvImg);

    IplImage gray = imgProc.rgbToGrey(img);

    grayscale.showImage(gray);

    IplImage binaryImg = imgProc.getBinary(gray);

    binary.showImage(binaryImg);

    IplImage multiplyImage = imgProc.cvCopyImages(binaryImg, input2);

    cvMultiplyAcc.showImage(multiplyImage);

    IplImage hsvImg2 = imgProc.rgbToHSV(multiplyImage);

    hsv2.showImage(hsvImg2);

    CvHistogram hueHistogram = imgProc.getHueHistogram(hsvImg2);

    System.out.println("Done");

    System.out.printf("max hist value is: ", imgProc.getHistMaxValue(hueHistogram));

}
```

}

Also here is the cvCopyImage method:

```
        public static IplImage cvCopyImages (IplImage binary, IplImage color){

    IplImage result = cvCreateImage(new CvSize(color.width(),color.height()),color.depth(),3);

    cvCopy(color,result,binary);

    return result;

}
```

Comment: It looks like a channel or format mismatch. can you please give us an example image and a simplified version of your code?

Comment: @RadfordParker added the requested info, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user2041427 it is not clear whether you are implying the error is non-deterministic or 1/5 of times you have different images that gives  incorrect results. If the later, then include two images that shows the problem. Disclaimer: I never looked into your code.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant that the error was non-deterministic, It seems to happen randomly but often so I guessed that it happens about once every 5 runthroughs of the program.

Comment: @user2041427 I'm not sure you understood my comment in its entirety. Are you claiming that given two images (and always the same two images), the program will sometimes give the correct results, and sometimes not ? /OR/, is it a combination of certain two images that gives the incorrect results ?

Comment: The former, the exact same images are loaded to the program each time, but the results vary I added another image to the post to demonstrate a good result from the exact same images.

Comment: I get the following result: http://i.imgur.com/XDxnA72.png by using http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FwFdqwdX. But, if you give the same input every time to this code, and it spits different results, then it is possible that these bindings for javacv are broken, and you are seeing the results of memory corruption.

Comment: Would cleaning (via garbage collector) up images and objects after the filters have been applied help with this at all? I have re-installed opencv and JavaCV and am still getting this behavior.